# npm @types and TypeScript version

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

So we have an issue in that the files being installed via npm on our build machine are differing from those files which are being used locally on our developer's machines.

We are using TypeScript, so require the `@types` to be installed for some of the npm packages, so in our package.json file, we have...

```
"dependencies": {
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.4"
}
"devDependencies": {        
    "@types/react-autosuggest": "^9.3.3"
}
```

On a fresh npm install locally, this is pulling down the types file, and in the file at the top it says;

```
// Type definitions for react-autosuggest 9.3
// Project: http://react-autosuggest.js.org/
// Definitions by: Nicolas Schmitt <https://github.com/nicolas-schmitt>
//                 Philip Ottesen <https://github.com/pjo256>
//                 Robert Essig <https://github.com/robessog>
//                 Terry Bayne <https://github.com/tbayne>
//                 Christopher Deutsch <https://github.com/cdeutsch>
//                 Kevin Ross <https://github.com/rosskevin>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
// TypeScript Version: 2.6
```

However, the version on the Build server is;

```
// Type definitions for react-autosuggest 9.3
// Project: http://react-autosuggest.js.org/
// Definitions by: Nicolas Schmitt <https://github.com/nicolas-schmitt>
//                 Philip Ottesen <https://github.com/pjo256>
//                 Robert Essig <https://github.com/robessog>
//                 Terry Bayne <https://github.com/tbayne>
//                 Christopher Deutsch <https://github.com/cdeutsch>
//                 Kevin Ross <https://github.com/rosskevin>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
// TypeScript Version: 2.8
```

Notice Version difference for TypeScript.

So for what ever reason, the file type seems to be the same, 9.3, but there is something not quite right. Locally we are now seeing different behaviour vs what is being published to the live environment.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File `package.json` doesn't store all dependencies tree with sub-dependencies and versions. For that at Node.js ecosystem there are `package-lock.json`/`yarn.lock`.

**You should store your `package-lock.json`/`yarn.lock` at git repository for repeatability.**

Comment: Ahh ok so you think the issue is the package-lock file?

Comment: 1️⃣Add `package-lock.json` file to git.
2️⃣Remove `node_modules` for every environment.
3️⃣Run `npm install`
You have repetability!